# problem with converting XML file to CSV file in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, converters

I use code below to convert XML to CSV file

but the result is :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Can anyone help?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd
  
cols = ["Id", "UserId", "Name", "Date", "Class", "TagBased"]
rows = []

xmlparse = Xet.parse('Badges.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()


for i in root:
    Id = i.find("Id").text
    userId = i.find("UserId").text
    name = i.find("Name").text
    date = i.find("Date").text
    Class = i.find("Class").text
    tagBased = i.find("TagBased").text
  
    rows.append({
                 "Id": Id,
                 "UserId": userId,
                 "Name": name,
                 "Date": date,
                 "Class": Class,
                 "TagBased": tagBased  
                })
  
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

MY data like:

```
<badges> 
<row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2014-04-17T00:58:09.973" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
<row Id="2890885" UserId="6775155" Name="Yearling" Date="2021-12-05T03:07:26.740" Class="2" TagBased="False" /> 
<row Id="2890886" UserId="5298879" Name="Yearling" Date="2021-12-05T03:07:26.740" Class="2" TagBased="False" /> 
</badges>
```

Comment: Your *i* node doesn't have an subelement with one of the names. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find. Check for *None* before referring *.text*.

Comment: My data like this, how can I do it? <badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2014-04-17T00:58:09.973" Class="3" TagBased="False" /><row Id="2890885" UserId="6775155" Name="Yearling" Date="2021-12-05T03:07:26.740" Class="2" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="2890886" UserId="5298879" Name="Yearling" Date="2021-12-05T03:07:26.740" Class="2" TagBased="False" /> </badges>

Comment: Those are not subnodes but attributes of the node. You should be able to access them like: `i.attrib.get("Id")`. Let me know if it works. And please do not add additional info in comments, edit the question instead!

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

Here's a simpler variant.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


COLS = ["Id", "UserId", "Name", "Date", "Class", "TagBased"]

def main(*argv):
    tree = ET.parse("./badges.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    rows = []
    for i in root:
        rows.append({col: i.attrib.get(col) for col in COLS})
        # The line above does the same thing as the 4 (commented) lines below. Listed them here for simplicity.
        #d = {}
        #for col in COLS:
        #    d[col] = i.attrib.get(col)
        #rows.append(d)

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=COLS)
    df.to_csv("./output.csv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070634926]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> badges.xml
> code00.py
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> badges.xml
> code00.py
> output.csv
>
> [prompt]> type output.csv
> ,Id,UserId,Name,Date,Class,TagBased
> 0,1,2,Autobiographer,2014-04-17T00:58:09.973,3,False
> 1,2890885,6775155,Yearling,2021-12-05T03:07:26.740,2,False
> 2,2890886,5298879,Yearling,2021-12-05T03:07:26.740,2,False
> ```